# Unable to run a SpecFlow scenario from Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2012, specflow

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Edition and configured SpecFlow. I have used the following configuration to run the tests in config.xml file:

```
<specFlow>
<unitTestProvider name="MsTest" /> 
</specFlow>
```

I was able to create the testes and compile properly. But when I tried to run the scenarios from the context menu with the option "Run SpecFlow Scenarios" or "Debug SpecFlow scenarios", I am not able to see any action. It just says "Build succeeded" and nothing else happens later.

Can someone kindly explain if there is any other way of executing the scenarios?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

I already had all this configuration set, but I was still not able to get the scenarios to run from the context menu.

Until I reviewed the **SpecFlow options** (Tools > Options > SpecFlow) and set "**VisualStudio2012**" as **Test Runner Tool** (under Test Execution).

For some reason it was set on "VisualStudio2010MsTest" and then the scenarios didn't run from the context menu.

Comment: For me, this solved the issue of not being able to run SpecFlow scenario's by just doing a right click and 'run' in the Solution Explorer in VS2012. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks, in VS2013, tool was set to auto.. Nothing happened when I tried to run my tests. Setting to ReSharper solved my problem!

Comment: I had to do this to get the context menu option to run Resharper instead of the built in test runner.

Comment: thank you. this was not an obvious bug. I have VS 2013 and i find it strange that setting the test runner to VS2012  fixes it. I'm happy it works, i don't have to understand why.

Answer (score 7):

Your app.config file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Configuration) to SpecFlow wiki.

Then re-build your solution and you should be able to see and run the tests. You can see and run your tests from Test/Windows/Test Explorer.

Also make sure that you have a reference to: Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework from your test project.
Here are the steps:

1. Create new project: In my case MVC 4
2. Add "Unit Test Project" to the solution
3. Add SpecFlow nuget package to "Unit Test Project"
4. Add one random SpecFlow feature/test 5) Run the test to make sure
   it works

Comment: I have the same settings in the configuration file but still I am not able to run at least a single test case in VS 2012. However I am able to run the tests in VS 2010. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this is a very old post. I was having the same issue for last 4 days and finally I solved it with random StackOverflow links. To save time for other developers it may help:

1. Change ReSharper version from 10 to 8.2
2. Tools > Extension & Update > Search online > NUnit Test Adapter > Install
3. Visual Studio 2013
4. Specflow Latest version
5. Install Unit test provider NUnit using command window of the nuget package manager. Tools-> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console. Run this in the window - Install Package specflow.Nunit
6. Restart Visual Studio.
7. Go to > something.Feature > right click on scenario description > **run unit test** OR **run specflow scenario**.
   Unit test session should appear.

Hope it will help others having the same issue.